# Inject specific instance into specific class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Is it possible to determine which class wants do inject my bean using Spring Context? I'm using the Java only configuration for my beans.

Let's say I've got this bean:

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public Helper helper() {
    return new Helper();
}
```

Now I want to know in which class this instance will be injected in to inject a special instance meant for this class.

I want to do something like this, example pseudo code:

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public Helper helper(Class injectInto) {
    if (injectInto == SomeClass.class) {
        return new Helper("Only for SomeClass!");
    }
    return new Helper();
}
```

The beans should be injected as always, for example:

```
@Autowired
private Helper helper;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the @Qualifier and @Bean(name="") annotations for this purpose. There are many online resources for how to use it.

```
@Bean(name="normal")
@Scope("prototype")
public Helper helper(Class injectInto) {
    return new Helper();
}

@Bean(name="special")
@Scope("prototype")
public Helper helper(Class injectInto) {
    return new Helper("Only for SomeClass!");
}
```

Autowire in SomeClass:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "special")
private Helper helper;
```